# IntelliJ unable to resolve certain types, ex: EnumValue on a Mongo record - Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, lift, intellij-scala

For Example:

```
object CampaignTypes extends Enumeration {

  type CampaignType = Value

  val ABC,DEF = Value
}

object campaignTypeId extends EnumNameField(this, CampaignTypes) {
    override val defaultValue = CampaignTypes.ABC
  }
```

IntelliJ underlines CampaignTypes.ABC in red with message Expression of type CampaignTypes.Value doesn't conform to expected type EnumType#Value

The code compiles & works. But, IntelliJ marks it as an error, making it difficult to read code (as there are many other cases, which is also not resolved by IntelliJ). The right Scala plugin is also used. Is there a way to resolve this?

Another example w.r.t methods defined on a BsonRecord

```
sealed trait Product {...}

class Document extends BsonRecord[Document] {
  object productType extends StringField(this, 20)
  ....
  def toTyped: Option[Product] = this.productType.get match {//something which returns an Option[Product] from a List[Product]}
}

object documents extends BsonRecordListField(this, Document) {
    def toProducts: Set[Product] =
      this.get.flatMap(_.toTyped)(breakOut) //Cannot resolve symbol toTyped
}
```

Comment: try File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart ?

Comment: tried it a couple of times before & now. Didn't work :(

Comment: Which version of IDEA and scala plugin do you use? If it still the case with 2018.2, please create an issue, ideally with an example of a project:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: Have you tried providing the correct Manifest to add a compiler hint ?

Comment: @niktrop  IDEA version 2018.2.1 , Build (#IC-182.3911.13) & Scala Plugin version 2018.2.9 

 We have created 2 issues already for this. Unfortunately hasn't got the priority yet.

 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13324
 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13325

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can help Intellij by providing type hints :

```
object campaignTypeId extends EnumNameField[A, CampaignsTypes.type](this, CampaignTypes) {
    override val defaultValue = CampaignTypes.ABC
  }
```

where `A` is the type of the encapsulating class/object

For a general solution :

- Try to always provide generic types instead of relying on inference, as you can see the one in Intellij IDEA is not great in diffucult cases.
- If that doesn't cut it, try to provide compiler hints. Lift relies on Manifest, but it can be classTag or other things. Expliciting this kind of implicits can help IDEA resolve types correctly

For BsonRecordListField, expliciting generic types should solve it too.

Comment: Thanks. This helps with resolve errors for Enums. But these are just one type of resolve errors.Just added another example to the question.

Comment: I edited my answer. In the future, please refrain from editing your question to add other problems in it, SO is meant to answer specific questions. 

If an answer solves your problem but raises another question, please post another question !